# Substraction between pairs of lines in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have been trying to add a new column to my data frame resulting from the substraction of the values of one column by pairs of lines for each "sub-data frame" (each "id_n").

My data frame looks like this:
[image]

```
dput(df[1:30,c(2,5,6,9,14,15)])
```

structure(list(gen_spe = c("holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads",
"holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads",
"holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads",
"holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads",
"holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads",
"holo_ads", "holo_ads", "holo_ads"), ori = c("guad", "guad",
"guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad",
"guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad",
"guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad", "guad",
"guad", "guad", "guad", "guad"), spe = c("ads", "ads", "ads",
"ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads",
"ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads",
"ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads", "ads"
), id_n = c("1_1", "1_1", "1_1", "1_1", "1_10", "1_10", "1_10",
"1_10", "1_11", "1_11", "1_11", "1_11", "1_12", "1_12", "1_12",
"1_12", "1_13", "1_13", "1_13", "1_13", "1_14", "1_14", "1_14",
"1_15", "1_15", "1_15", "1_16", "1_16", "1_16", "1_16"), npu = c(1,
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2,
3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4), duper = c(0.00997, 0.01002, 0.01213,
NA, 0.01049, 0.01024, 0.01292, NA, 0.01054, 0.01009, 0.01424,
NA, 0.01088, 0.01027, 0.01444, NA, 0.0102, 0.00995, 0.01165,
NA, 0.01079, 0.01047, NA, 0.01061, 0.01129, NA, 0.01038, 0.0102,
0.01317, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

So, we have something like :

```
id_n <- c("1_1","1_1","1_1","1_1","2_1","2_2","2_3","2_4","3_1","3_2")
duper <- c("0.00997","0.01002","0.01213", "NA", "0.01024", "0.01024", "0.01258", "NA", "0.01045", "0.01020")
npu <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2")
x <- data.frame(id_n, duper, npu)
```

I would like R to give me a new column that corresponds to the substraction of values of column 'duper' 2 by 2 for each id_n.

For example, for id_n = 1_1 : `0.01002-0.00997; 0.01213-0.01002.` 
For id_n = 1_2 : `0.01024-0.01024;  0.01258-0.01024.`
For id_n = 1_3 : `0.01061-0.01047`
And so on.

I am able to make a list of the 'sub-data frames' on which I then would like to apply a funcion but I do not know how to ask R to calculate this.
The column 'npu' could be used as values go from 1 to ... for each id_n.

Do you have some ideas?

Thank you very much,

Marine.

Comment: Please do not post photos of data or code! If you do, people who are willing to help you would have to type out all that text. Instead provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please just provide the dput(head(name of your dataset)) in order to help you

Comment: Sorry, I added some information and simple code to explain what I try to do. I hope this is fine!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (using `tidyverse` library):

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

x$duper <- as.numeric(x$duper)

x %>%
  group_by(id_n) %>%
  mutate(new_col = duper - lag(duper))
```

Returns this result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id_n [7]
   id_n     duper npu      new_col
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 1_1    0.00997 1     NA        
 2 1_1    0.0100  2      0.0000500
 3 1_1    0.0121  3      0.00211  
 4 1_1   NA       4     NA        
 5 2_1    0.0102  1     NA        
 6 2_2    0.0102  2     NA        
 7 2_3    0.0126  3     NA        
 8 2_4   NA       4     NA        
 9 3_1    0.0104  1     NA        
10 3_2    0.0102  2     NA
```

Comment: Thank you denisafonin ! 

For the whole data frame, I have to write it like this :

`df <- df %>%
  group_by(id_n) %>%
  mutate(new_col = duper - lag(duper))`